# Resetting a Formik field array to an empty array prior to form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I'm using Formik as part of my React app with FieldArray. Taking the following example over at CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/3yv7135981?file=/form.js together with the following the values/props sample:

```
props = {
  "values": {
    "plantTitle": "Test",
    "streetAddress": "2222",
    "city": {
      "value": "Gainesville",
      "label": "Gainesville"
    },
    "country": {
      "value": "United States of America",
      "label": "United States of America"
    },
    "descr": "rererere",
    "categories": [
      {
        "value": "Skin & Personal Care",
        "label": "Skin & Personal Care",
        "color": "#f47f20"
      }
    ],
    "nodes": [
      {
        "node_label": "municipal",
        "node_categories": [],
        "cost": "11",
        "currencyUnit": "usd",
        "volume": "1",
        "volumeUnit": "gallons",
        "accuracy": "estimated",
        "numFeeds": "",
        "comment": "qaz",
        "fedInto": []
      },
      {
        "node_label": "ground",
        "node_categories": [],
        "cost": "22",
        "currencyUnit": "usd",
        "volume": "33",
        "volumeUnit": "cubic_meters",
        "accuracy": "measured",
        "numFeeds": "",
        "comment": "dsdsds",
        "fedInto": []
      }
    ]
  }
```

How would I go about resetting the **nodes[]** field array alone but still maintaining all the values above for `plantTitle, streetAddress` etc prior to submitting the overall form?

I have tried `setFieldValue(nodes, [])` but to no avail. I basically just need to reset the nodes back to an empty array and allow the user to re-enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've forked the sandbox you've provided. you were almost there with `setFieldValue`. You may just have missed some
quotation marks (`"nodes"`).

```
onClick={() => setFieldValue("nodes", [])}
```

[Fork of the codesandbox with setFieldValue("nodes", [])](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-fieldarray-actually-works-forked-wqlk6?file=/form.js:16783-16834)

Comment: That is is looking good but just wanted to check that `setFieldValue()` works within `<Formik>.....</Formik>` tags and that `setFieldValue("nodes", [])` can also be used standalone (i.e. not part of an onClick event as I am looking at calling it as part of a conditional component render?

Comment: I haven't used Formik that much honestly. However, you should be able to as long as it's inside of a `<Formik>` tag or `withFormik` with it. Even if it's not on an event handler.

Comment: FYI, it seems like inorder for it to work, it needs to be part of an event handler as it didn't work as a standalone call. All good now.